# URLの末尾から2つ分のパス要素を取り出したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

例えば、

```
https://example.com/theater/13/130301/3271/
```

というURLからISBNをあらわす

```
130301/3271/
```

をキーとして抜き出したいです。

```
sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 1
```

のようなエラーが出てしまうのですが、どうしたらいいのか調べてもわからないので教えてください。

プログラムは以下のようになっています。

```python
import re

url = 'https://example.com/theater/13/130301/3271/'
m = re.search(r'/(^/([^/]+)$',url)
print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: 質問に記載するコードは、[「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)に従い、エラーを確認できる最小限のものにすると回答が得られやすいです。次回以降、参考にして下さい。

Answer (score 2):

> missing ),

というのは、あるはずの `)` が見つからない（足りない）、ということです。
開きかっこ「`(`」が2つあるのに、閉じかっこ「`)`」が1つしかなく、対応していないことが原因です。
グループを1つ作るとすると、下記のようになるかと思います。

```
import re

url = 'https://example.com/theater/13/130301/3271/'
m = re.search(r'([^/]+/[^/]+/)$', url)
print(m.group(1))
```

出力:

```
130301/3271/
```

ちなみに、この場合でしたらマッチ全体が望む結果なので、グループは作らなくてもよいです。
`group` メソッドは引数を省略すると `0` と見なされ、`0` はマッチ全体を意味します。

```
m = re.search(r'[^/]+/[^/]+/$', url)
print(m.group())
```